# Deploy Odoo on Google Kubernetes: Log severity all in ERROR

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, odoo

I deploy Odoo 13CE on Googke Kubernetes and using Cloud Logging for logging, I config app using default container log.

Everything run smoothly, except **all log output severity mark as ERROR in Cloud Loging**

[image]

- Can I change default Odoo ouput log format to [JSON](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry)?
- (or) Overwrite function `init_logger()` to make it work with deploy env?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone have this problem, I have fixed this issue following these steps:

- In `odoo.conf` add config: `cloud_logging = True`
- Patch file `odoo/netsvc.py` [source here](https://github.com/NothingCtrl/odoo-13-base/blob/5bd65715f8496122a3a5d6f9cd2f90bbf9880579/patch/odoo/odoo/netsvc.py) to [attaching the Cloud Logging handler](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python) to the Python root logger
- Suppress default log output by config `odoo.conf` log file: `logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo.log` (to avoid duplicate log in Cloud Logging)

[image: cloud logging after patch]